# Issues sending a form with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I'm having trouble self-submitting a form that I call with an ajax code on document ready. I want it remain on index.php as the user clicks submit, however the code does not seem live and takes me immediately to new_work.php instead. From what I've read you don't need to use preventDefault and stopPropagation with ajaxForm.

```
var initAjaxForm = function() {
    ('#ajax_form').ajaxForm({
        success: function(data) {
            $('body').html(data); 
        }
        });   
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').load("new_work.php", function() {
        initAjaxForm();
    });
});
```

Nothing important in the html markup. Just an empty skeleton with a form

`<form action="new_work.php" method="post" id="ajax_form">`

I'm using the ajaxform plugin because that's the only way I know to send files via ajax. If there's a better solution, please let me know! Thank you.

Edit: the error I get is:

Uncaught TypeError: Object #ajax_form has no method 'ajaxForm'

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#download)? ajaxForm is not built into standard jQuery.

Is `ajax_form` the id of an HTML form?

Comment: Yes to both. I posted the form header in the OP.

Comment: Is that form header in `index.php` or `new_work.php`? If in the former, it will be overwritten by the `load`, and gone by the time ajaxForm is called.

Comment: It's in new_work.php... What can I do to make it work after the load is called?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a dollar sign;

```
$('#ajax_form').ajaxForm({
```

Comment: D'oh. That gets rid of the error. But the code still takes me to new_work.php

Comment: Why is the php file in your body load? Try just having the function call.

Comment: I guess it doesn't have to be, but I put it there to help me better organize my pages. It works with just the function call if I don't get the data using an ajax call first. But I guess even hypothetically I'd like to solve the reason why and get it to work this way without having the form there from the start.